# How to save application data for use across users in OS X

Tags: java, macos, sqlite

I have a Mac Java application that needs to persist data across reboots.  The data needs to be saved so that any user has access to it.  E.g. an SQLite database file that can be used for all users.

It looks like the /Library/Application Support/ folder is supposed to be used for this, but I'm not able to write to it without making my app run as root or changing the permissions of the file to rwxrwxrwx.

What is the proper way to save application-level data on Mac?

Comment: Pick a local file - create a hidden directory and stuff your application data into that.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Barranka Code level questions are off topic on Ask Different.

Comment: What should happen when two users save different values for the same thing?

Comment: Two users won't be running the app at the same time so there is no risk of contention.  This is more like a common properties file or database.  I have added the example of SQLite database for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer documentation covering this is a bit of a large topic:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_DataManagement_MacOSX/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009046
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672

According to the [File System Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) you should make a specific subdirectory inside `/Library/Application\ Support` for your app to store app data common to all users on the system. I'd use [reverse domain name notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation) such as com.yourcompany.yourapp or something else unlikely to collide with another app's use of the common directory for this.

You might also look into using an existing app bundler for OS X such as https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler rather than hard code paths to file locations.

Comment: Apps are not able to write to files in `/Library/Application\ Support/com.mydomain.myapp/myfile.db` without root permissions or me making everything in `com.mydomain.myapp` universally writable.

Comment: @BHarman The permissions in /Library are as user-hostile as in /Applications - you'll want an installer to escalate permissions and set appropriate privileges for your design.

Comment: So there isn't an issue with having something in /Library be set up with full write access?

Comment: @BHarman It's unconventional, but java isn't the typical language on OS X. Most apps now run as signed / sandboxed apps with proper entitlements to describe where on the filesystem they read and write. See this post towards the bottom about containerizing a java app and making it sandbox proof. It's for more typical, user only data storage, but should help you decide how to move forward. http://www.intransitione.com/blog/take-java-to-app-store/#stepthree